# jQuery show/hide element when hovering another element

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML as an example:

```
<div id="header">
<div class="pagination"></div>
</div>
```

and the following jQuery which should hide the pagination by default but then fade it in when a user hovers the header and then fades it back out when they move off the header:

```
            $(".pagination").hide();
            $("#header").mousemove(function()
            {
                $(".pagination").fadeIn(1500);
            });
            $("#header").mouseleave(function()
            {
                $(".pagination").fadeOut(1500);
            });
```

The problem I have is that it will run through the code the same number of times a user hovers the header so for example if I hovered 5 times in a row the pagination would fade in and out 5 times. This is not the function I want, rather a simple fade in and out when a user is hovering the header.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, you could chain those as well `$("header").mousemove(...).mouseleave(...);`

Comment: +1 : the question is readable and clear! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well than instead of `fadeIn` - `fadeOut` just use `.fadeTo` like in my

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YPLQn/)

And to stop the issue you are talking about use `.stop()`

Good Luck!

Comment: That works :) Seem like `stop()` was the magic bit of code I was looking for. Cheers

Comment: @Cameron not exactly! use .stop() with fadeIn or fadeOut and you'll get another issue! try and see! :) Take care. ..and thanks

Answer (score 4):

Edited: Added some code to avoid repeated fading in and out.

```
     var running = false;

     $("#header").hover(function()
        {
            if(!running){
               $(".pagination").fadeIn(1500);
               running = true;
            }
        }, function()
        {
            $(".pagination").fadeOut(1500, function(){
                running = false;
            });
        });
```

Now, the hover effect only kicks in if it is not already running.

Comment: Still fades the pagination in x number of times though!